# archive file zips when doing an Artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

The problem is the folowing:

I have two jenkins jobs A and B.

In the A job, I use the post-build Action: Archive the artifacts, to Archive 4 .jar files: the problem is that, unlike only archiving one file, the folder archive zips: so archive is archive.zip and inside that zip I have the 4 jars.

The in B I use the Copy Artifact Plugin to copy the artifacts from A to B and the error is the folowing:

```
 Unable to access upstream artifacts area C:\***\builds\15\archive. Does source project archive artifacts?

 ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from 1PrepareAndCompileSquemas with filter: *.jar
```

The *** are folders in the middle.

If I take the archive.zip file, i unzip it and Y put in a folder called archive in the same path, the jobs works correctly so the problem is that when at A I save the artifacts those are saved to a .zip file

there is any way to save this artifacts without ziping the archive folder?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I have configurated an option to compress the artifacts at Global confiiguration